# How to insert a CSV into Mysql with Xampp shell

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am trying to upload a sql file in the database I am running following code

```
# mysql - u root -p idecon123 < "d:\IdeOffline\answersnew.sql"
```

But when I parse this it shows the help manual .

Is there any mistake in my command

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://localhost/ after starting Apache and MySQL.  On the left side you will see a link for phpMyAdmin.  Click that, then upload your `.sql` file through the browser.  See http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/import for how to import files.

**edit**: for big files, set an `uploadDir` per http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html .  Copy the file into that directory and you'll be able to import it directly.

Comment: the file is of around 2 GB That is taking way too much time , Even after editing the .ini files etc .

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the mysqlimport command in the command prompt.

Here is the syntax,

```
mysqlimport -u root -p abc@123 --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by="," --lines-terminated-by="\n" --local upam_dev C:\Users\ukrishnan\Desktop\Generated-Players\PlayerProfile.dataSet-1.csv
```

`--ignore-line - To exclude if you have something like title in your first line of CSV`

`--fields-terminated-by - Can specify, how the field is terminated like , or | symbol`

The filenames must correspond with the tables into which their data will be imported. If a filename contains one or more . (dots), the portion before the first dot will be assumed to be the name of the table.

If you have data in multiple files, you can specify like Profile.File-1.csv, Profile.File-2.csv. So that it will take the table name as `Profile` when you import these files.

These is ultimately fast when compare with the importing through PhpMyAdmin. It took me around 3-4 seconds to import a file with 100K records.